# Herkunft von »der was«

Tags: dialect, relative-pronoun

Im Osten Österreichs (wahrscheinlich auch weiter westlich, und möglicherweise auch in Bayern) werden im Dialekt Nebensätze gerne mal mit *»der was«, »die was«* oder *»das was«* eingeleitet. Auf ein erstes Relativpronomen (*der, die, das*) folgt also unmittelbar noch ein zweites (*was*).

Beispiele:

> Der Thomas ist der dort drüben, **der was** sich gerade die Schuhe zubindet.
>   Das ist die Lisa, **die was** ich beim Töpfern kennengelernt habe.
>   Naja, zum Glück gibt's das auch bei Billa, sein gutes Fleisch, **das was** zu 100 % aus Österreich ist.

Das letze Zitat stammt übrigens aus einer [Fernsehwerbung](https://vimeo.com/20200192), die vor einigen Jahren in Österreich ausgestrahlt wurde, und wegen dieser *das-was*-Phrase die Gemüter im Lande erhitzt hat. (Dass der ganze Spot in einer Mischung aus Hochdeutsch und Wiener Dialekt gesprochen wurde, hat jedoch niemanden gestört.) Nach einigen Wochen wurde der Spot durch eine Version ersetzt, die ohne das *»was«* im letzen Satz auskam, sonst aber genau gleich war.

Diese Konstruktion hört man relativ oft. Sie zu verwenden gilt aber unter denen, die diese Konstruktion ablehnen, als untrügliches Kennzeichen für eine Herkunft aus bildungsfernen Schichten. Trotz dieser Stigmatisierung hält sich diese Konstruktion aber äußerst stabil unter Dialektsprechern. Unbestritten ist aber, dass es sich dabei um keine standardsprachliche Konstruktion handelt.

Ich frage mich nun schon seit längerem, wie alt diese Konstruktion ist, wie sie entstanden ist, und warum man sie nur im Süden kennt. Ich halte zwei Varianten für möglich, die aber nur die Verbreitung, nicht aber die Entstehung erklären könnten:

1. Die Verwendung von zwei Relativpronomen war (zumindest in dem Gebiet, in dem Hochdeutsch gesprochen wurde) die ursprüngliche Art Relativsätze zu bilden. Weiter im Norden, wo Niederdeutsch (heute nur mehr als Plattdeutsch erhalten) gesprochen wurde, war das aber unüblich. Als sich Hochdeutsch nach Norden ausdehnte und Niederdeutsch fast vollständig verdrängte, wanderte aber die Art, nur ein Relativpronomen zu verwenden, in die Gegenrichtung, so dass schlussendlich im gesamten hochdeutschen Sprachraum die Verwendung von *»was«* in dieser Konstruktion als falsch angesehen wurde, und lediglich in den bayrischen Dialekten erhalten blieb.
2. Ursprünglich wurde sowohl in den hochdeutschen als auch in den niederdeutschen Regionen nur ein Relativpronomen verwendet. Später kam es aber im Süden des deutschen Sprachraums in Mode, auch noch ein *»was«* einzufügen.

Beide Versionen lassen aber die entscheidende Frage offen:
Wie kam es überhaupt dazu, dass zwei Relativpronomen hintereinander verwendet wurden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wie kam es überhaupt dazu, dass zwei Relativpronomen hintereinander verwendet wurden?

Bei dem *was* in diesen Relativsätzen handelt es sich nicht um das Pronomen, da es, wie die Beispiele zeigen, auch in Relativsätzen auftritt, die sich auf eine Person beziehen. Es zeigt also nicht die für das Pronomen typische Kongruenz. Als unveränderliches Wort wird es in der Literatur manchmal als Relativsatzpartikel bezeichnet.

Aber warum steht da überhaupt ein *was* (oder in anderen Dialekten ein *wo*)? Finite Nebensätze werden im Deutschen in der Regel von einem Subjunktor (*dass, ob, wenn, weil, ...*) eingeleitet. Dies gilt nur in zwei Fällen nicht: Bei den "indirekten Fragesätzen" (*Weißt du, **wer das ist**?*) und bei den Relativsätzen.

Es scheint plausibel, dass das *was* in den zitierten Relativsätzen in Analogie zu den Subjunktoren steht. (Es gibt auch Dialekte, in denen die Partikel allein auftritt.)

Nach kurzer Recherche konnte ich nicht viel passende Literatur im Netz finden. Vielleicht folgender Artikel:

Fleischer, Jürg (2018): Relativsatz-Einleitung. In: SyHD-atlas. http://www.syhd.info/apps/atlas/#relativsatz-einleitung

Answer (score -1):

"Der was" steht für "der, welcher". Es wird hier im Dialekt nur die unbelebte Form verwendet, und in den angegebenen Sätzen wurde das Komma weggelassen.

Hochdeutsch würde es z.B. folgendermaßen heißen:

> Der Thomas ist der dort drüben, der, welcher sich gerade die Schuhe zubindet.

Zur Entstehung lässt sich schwer etwas finden. Wahrscheinlich wurde früher einfach sprachlich im einfachen Volk kein Wert auf den Unterschied zwischen belebt und unbelebt gelegt (Wer/Was).

Comment: Wie sieht das mit unbelebten Objekten aus? In meinem Zitat aus der Fernsehwerbung würde ich *das gute Fleisch vom Billa* nicht unbedingt als belebt bezeichnen.

Comment: Da fehlt nur das Komma. Wahlweise kann man "was" mit "welches" ersetzen. Dann ist's normales Hochdeutsch.
"Naja, zum Glück gibt's das auch bei Billa, sein gutes Fleisch, das, was/welches zu 100 % aus Österreich ist."

Comment: Eher noch: "… der, der sich gerade die Schuhe zubindet". *Welcher* ist doch eigentlich mehr für einen dritten reserviert (da bin ich aber nicht sicher). "und nicht jener, welcher danebensteht."

Comment: @äüö: Ist das dein Ernst? *»... sein gutes Fleisch, das, welches zu 100 % aus Österreich ist.«* soll normales Hochdeutsch sein? Nie und nimmer! Um daraus einen korrekten standarddeutschen Satz zu machen, müsstest du entweder das Wort *»das«* oder das Wort *»welches«* zusammen mit einem Komma streichen. Welche grammatische Funktion sollen denn diese beiden Wörter im Satz haben?

Comment: Steht sogar schon in heiligen Schriften seit Jahrhunderten: 
https://books.google.de/books?id=klYNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=der+welcher+dort&source=bl&ots=vAI5lPqu9s&sig=qNJTBH7KSd7Bsp7NqSft9ydwLRQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMm4mqycLXAhUCGuwKHcEICowQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=der%20welcher%20dort&f=false    ist eine nachgeschobene Erklärung oder so etwas...

Comment: kannst auch "nämlich" einfügen, dann wird's vielleicht klarer: "... sein gutes Fleisch, nämlich das, welches zu 100%..."

Comment: Was soll das sein, eine unbelebte Form?

Answer (score -1):

> Wie kam es überhaupt dazu, dass zwei Relativpronomen hintereinander verwendet wurden?

"der was", "die was", "das was" ist einfacher konstruiert als "der, welcher", "die, welche" und "das, welches" (ich unterstelle mal das diese grammatikalische Konstruktion dahintersteckt). Der Dialektsprecher erspart sich das geistige Abrufen der richtigen Genusflexion und eine Silbe.

Warum dann aber das "das"? Die Bildung würde auch ohne funktionieren, etwa:

> Der Thomas ist der dort drüben, was sich gerade die Schuhe zubindet.

Ich habe das auch schon gehört. Es ist jedoch viel seltener und klingt schlampig. Sozusagen der Dialekt der Minimalisten.

Mein Fazit: Wie bei vielen Dialektkonstruktionen entzieht sich auch diese dem Versuch, sie aus standardsprachlichen Konstruktionen herzuleiten. Die Bildung ist ein Kompromiß zwischen der Vermeidung des sperrigen "welche(r/s)" und der grammatikalisch naheliegenden Form "die, welche". Bleibt zu hoffen, daß es nicht Eingang in die Hochsprache findet, die was ja auch nicht immer logisch ist.

Comment: Am Beginn zitierst du zwar meine Frage, beantwortest sie aber nicht. Du erklärst nur, wie eines der beiden Relativpronomen zu einem anderen umgewandelt worden sein könnte, ohne aber zu erklären, warum es zwei sind. Denn »der welcher« sind ja auch zwei Relativpronomen hintereinander. Bei der zweiten Frage (»warum das "das"?«) gibst du auch keine Antwort auf die gestellte Frage, sondern sagt nur, dass es auch ohne ginge. Interessant wäre aber zu wissen, warum es **mit** dem »das« geht. Und am Ende wirst du wertend, das hilft auch niemandem.