# “Es gibt Menschen, die kein Haus haben”: what is “die” here?

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

I'm currently learning German using Duolingo, and I came across the sentence “Es gibt Menschen, die kein Haus haben.”

Duolingo says the translation is: “There are people who do not have a house.”

I don't understand how *die* is translated to *who*.

If I wanted to say “There’s a person who likes cats,” would it be “Es gibt ein Person, die Kazen mag”?

Comment: Where exactly do you see a problem with the use of *die* for *who*? - What is your first language? In your first language, do you have something you would call a relative pronoun?

Comment: It is a very wonderful thing in German, learn it very carefully! All the languages I know, has a similar construction, but German does this on the most logical way. This is used in the alldays a lot, so you have to learn it well in both directions! But don't worry, it is easy (maybe a little bit harder as the modelverbs). Sometimes there is a quite complex relativpronom + modalverb + passive construction (z.B. "die Aufgaben, die erledigt werden konnten, wurden all erledigt"), particularly in Big Company environment, you have to learn also them.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann My 2 native languages are English and Hebrew, only languages I know. Non of them have this weird way of relative pronouns, so it was new to me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

> Es gibt Menschen, die kein Haus haben

"die" is a relative pronoun, introducing the relative clause, just like "who" is in English.

Your second example is nearly correct, it should be

> Es gibt eine Person, die Katzen mag

Note in German relative pronouns need to follow the subject they relate to in gender and number (unlike in English that distinguishes between persons and non-persons), so

> Es gibt einen Mann, **der** Katzen mag
>
> Es gibt eine Frau, **die** Katzen mag
>
> Es gibt ein Kind, **das** Katzen mag
>
> Es gibt Leute, **die** Katzen mögen

Comment: My other sentence was "There's a person who likes cats", doesn't you second sentence (Es gibt eine Person, die keine Katzen mag) mean "There's a person who *doesn't* like cats"?

Comment: It's OK, as I said it's a minor thing, just wanted to make sure it was ACTUALLY a minor error rather than something huge I've missed :)

Comment: Decided your example people now actually *like* cats ;)

Comment: Is this relative clause also used to say "that"? as in "There's a car that can fly"?

Comment: Yep. "Es gibt ein Auto, **das** fliegen kann" - Second but last example

Answer (score 5):

The word *die* is a [relative pronoun](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Relativpronomen,_m,_f) here. It is plural (and nominative, because it is the subject of the relative clause). Your other example is almost correct, but only because *Person* is feminine. So it would be

> Es gibt eine Person, die...

but

> Es gibt einen Menschen, der...
>
> Es gibt ein Individuum, das...

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(The following is just a side note to the perfectly satisfying answers of Carsten S and Tofro.)</sub>

There are some dialects of German where they use *wo* quite the same way English does:

> Do isch a Mââ, **wo** Katza maa. [Da ist ein Mann, **der** Katzen mag]
>
> Do isch a Frau, **wo** Hond it riacha kaa. [Da ist eine Frau, **die** Hunde nicht riechen kann]

But note: the English *who* can be used only for persons, the South German dialectal "wo" is a full relative pronoun able to replace anything:

> Do isch a Schiff, **wo** blaue Seegl hot. [Da ist ein Schiff, das blaue Segel hat.]

Examples used here are from Swabian, a dialect spoken in Germany's south-west. The phenomenon is, however, not restricted to that dialect.

Comment: It's the same with *was* or *wat* in Northern German dialects.

Comment: Confused: do you equate "wo" and "who"? Since you seem to indicate that "wo" is dialectal for "wer"("der") a clarification might help to avoid the false friend dilemma of reading "wo" like in "wohin/woher."

Comment: it = nicht? (In »wo Hond **it** riacha kaa«.) Sollte das nicht eher *nit* sein? Darüber hinaus muss ich LangLangC Recht geben: wo ≠ who. Sondern: wo = where; wer = who.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "it", "nit", "ett", "etta", "net", "netta" - All southwest-German for "nicht" - Thinking about it, a pretty negative group of dialects...

Comment: Ich nehme an, der zitierte Dialekt ist Schwäbisch? In Österreich (wo ebenfalls "South German dialect" gesprochen wird, aber eben doch etwas anderes als Schwäbisch) würden die Sätze wie folgt lauten: *»Do is a Mau, **der wos** Kotzn mog.« »Do is a Frau, **die wos** kane Hund riachn kau.« »Do is a Schiff, **des wos** blaue Segl hot.«* Siehe auch: [Herkunft von »der was«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38032/1487)

Comment: I find any relation between "der wo" and "the ... who" pretty far-fetched as well. The correlation between "wos"/"was" and "wo" is, however, not much closer. I suppose it's rather a "woher"/"wohin" connection.